# Unpin the Microsoft Edge and store taskbar shortcuts programmatically

Tags: windows, powershell

I setup computers daily and I need to remove the Microsoft Edge and Store taskbar shortcuts.

I am having trouble creating a script and I have searched for other stackoverflow posts but they were not helpful to me.

Does anyone have a script that can unpin the MS Edge and Store taskbar shortcuts?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can unpin taskbar items by running the following PowerShell commands.

```
function Unpin-App([string]$appname) {
    ((New-Object -Com Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}').Items() |
        ?{$_.Name -eq $appname}).Verbs() | ?{$_.Name.replace('&','') -match 'Unpin from taskbar'} | %{$_.DoIt()}
}

Unpin-App("Microsoft Edge")
Unpin-App("Microsoft Store")
```

This should work for any application on the taskbar. If the application isn't found, the error `InvokeMethodOnNull` will be thrown.

What this does:

- Enumerates the Shell/taskbar COM object namespace
- Matches the item with the name `$appname` (in this case, Edge and Store)
- Gets the verb `Unpin from taskbar` of that com object
- Executes the verb to remove it from the taskbar (without having to kill explorer.exe)

Comment: This is great; 2 important notes, though: 1. for me "Store" didn't work. So I used `((New-Object -Com Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}').Items())` to get the list, copied  to an editor searched and found that "Windows Store" should be used instead. 2. `((New-Object -Com Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}').Items() | ?{$_.Name -eq $appname}).Verbs()` is localized!! (facepalm) So I had to substitute "Unpin from taskbar" with "Открепить от панели задач" (Russian) and after that, the solution worked. Thanks!

Comment: It's "Microsoft Store" for me... but this answer is awesome!

Comment: Any way to have this apply to a different user?

Comment: Any idea how to unpin "File Explorer"? It has no "Unpin from taskbar" verb...

Answer (score 4):

Very nice solution from Judge2020, +1

- With a RegEx and -match instead of -eq you can unpin several Apps in one run
- The unpin verbs are localized, in German it's `Von "Start" lösen`

---

```
$appnames = "^Microsoft Edge$|^Store$"
((New-Object -Com Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}').Items() | 
  Where-Object{$_.Name -match $appnames}).Verbs() | 
  Where-Object{$_.Name.replace('&','') -match 'Unpin from taskbar|Von "Start" lösen'} | 
  ForEach-Object{$_.DoIt(); $exec = $true}
```

Comment: Any way to have this apply to a different user?